# Как работает оператор (). С++

Tags: c++

Например у меня есть функция `int foo() {return 0;};`. И где нибудь в `main` я буду вызывать `foo()` , а как оператор `()` работает в данном случае ?

Comment: Осуществляет вызов функции? Нет?

Comment: В плане `foo` это же указатель на функцию? А как вызов выглядит изнутри? Как компилятор это интерпретирует

Comment: Указатель на функцию в этом случае выглядит вот так int(*pfoo)() = &foo.

Comment: Амперсанд вроде не нужен, компилятор сам неявно преобразует `foo` в указатель

Comment: Если интересно то прочитайте про стековый фрейм функии. Любые параметры передаваемые из функции main() в функцию foo() копируют эти параметры из стекового фрейма main() в стековый фрейм foo()

Comment: @Kaznachei: `foo` - это не указатель на функцию. Это сама функция. Не надо путать.

Comment: Я и не говорил,. что `foo` это уазатель. Я говорю , что `int(*pfoo)() = &foo`, вроде как неверно, так как компилятор сам неявно в  случае, когда мы хотим присвоить какому-то указателю адрес функции, переопределит `foo` как указатель на функцию (себя) и получается, что нужно писать `int(*pfoo)() = foo`.

Comment: неявно преобразует

Answer (score 6):

- В выражении `foo()` используется комбинация символов `()`. Это может быть и оператор вызова функции, и часть синтаксиса приведения типа в функциональной нотации. Компилятор не может определить, что это такое, на основе лишь внешнего анализа синтаксиса.
- Слева от `()` находится идентификатор `foo`. Это приводит к запуску процесса *поиска имен* (name lookup), который ищет имя `foo` для того, чтобы выяснить, что же оно из себя представляет. Процесс поиска имен выясняет, что `foo` - это имя функции. Это значит, что слева от `()` располагается выражение типа "функция" и что `()` является именно оператором вызова функции. Также из этого следует, что в данном случае используется *встроенный* оператор `()`.
- Это приводит к запуску процесса *разрешения перегрузки* (overload resolution), который на основе имени `foo` и предоставленных аргументов выбирает самую подходящую версию функции `foo`. В вашем примере аргументов нет, а кандидат всего один. То есть процесс разрешения перегрузки выбирает именно вашу единственную функцию `foo`.
- Происходит вызов функции `foo`. И получение результата, если вы его получаете.

Вот так работает встроенный оператор `()`.

Comment: В третьем пункте вы про перегрузку функции?

Comment: @Kaznachei: Да, про нее самую.

Comment: Все пункты, кроме последнего выполняются на этапе компиляции?

Comment: @Александр: Под "вызовом" функции я в данном случае имел в виду финальное решение о вызове, генерацию кода для вызова. То есть все вышеописанное - на этапе компиляции.